# React js babel transform and minification in asp.net core

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, webpack, babeljs, bundling-and-minification

I have a asp.net core 2.0 application and I am using react.js also. I have some jsx files in that.
I want to minify those jsx files and then use. For js & css minification, 
I defined rules in `bundleconfig.json` but wiring rules for jsx throws errors.

[image]
[image]

Can anyone help me how I can minify jsx in asp.net core application.

**Update**
Below is my project structure
[image]

below is webpack.config file

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

process.traceDeprecation = true;

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        home: "./wwwroot/js/v2/userdefined/home.page.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot/dist"),
        filename: "[name].js",
        publicPath: "/dist/"
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                sourceMap: false,
                extractComments: 'all',
                uglifyOptions: {
                    compress: true,
                    output: null
                }
            }),
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
                cssProcessorOptions: {
                    safe: true,
                    discardComments: {
                        removeAll: true,
                    },
                },
            })
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\.\/locale$/, 'empty-module', false, /jsx$/),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {}
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
        }),
        new CompressionPlugin({
            test: /\.(js|css)/
        }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new WebpackShellPlugin({
            onBuildStart: ['echo "Starting postcss command"'],
            onBuildEnd: ['postcss --dir wwwroot/dist wwwroot/dist/*.css']
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve('./node_modules')
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        minimize: true,
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: ["babel-loader", "eslint-loader"]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
            loader: "file-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff|ttf|otf|eot|woff2|svg)$/i,
            loader: "file-loader"
        }
        ]
    }
};
```

below is Gruntfile.js

```
/// <binding AfterBuild='cleanup' />
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require("jit-grunt")(grunt);
  grunt.initConfig({
    clean: ["./Modules/*"],
    copy: {
      main: {
        expand: true,
        src: [
          "../Modules/**/bin/Debug/**/**/*.*",
          "../Modules/**/wwwroot/**",
        ],
        dest: "./Modules/"
      },
      css: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: "../Modules/AwesomeCMSCore.Modules.Frontend/wwwroot/dist",
        src: ["cmscore.css"],
        dest: "./wwwroot/dist/"
      },
      js: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: "../Modules/AwesomeCMSCore.Modules.Frontend/wwwroot/dist",
        src: ["*.js"],
        dest: "./wwwroot/dist/"
      },
      static: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: "../Modules/AwesomeCMSCore.Modules.Frontend/wwwroot/dist",
        src: ["**"],
        dest: "./wwwroot/dist/"
      }
    },
    watch: {
      css: {
        files: ["../Modules/**/wwwroot/dist/*.css"],
        tasks: ["copy:css"],
        options: {
          reload: true,
          spawn: false
        }
      },
      js: {
        files: ["../Modules/**/wwwroot/dist/*.js"],
        tasks: ["copy:js"],
        options: {
          reload: true,
          spawn: false
        }
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.registerTask("default", ["watch"]);
  grunt.registerTask("cleanup", [
    "clean",
    "copy:main",
    "copy:static"
  ]);
};
```

below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ProjV2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "JitendraPancholi",
  "license": "",
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "webpack -p --mode=production --config webpack.prod.js",
    "start": "webpack --mode=development --config webpack.dev.js",
    "lint:js": "eslint \"wwwroot/js/react/src/**/*.{js,jsx}\" --color",
    "lint:style": "stylelint \"wwwroot/css/**/*.scss\" --syntax scss"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "8.2.6",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "1.1.11",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.7",
    "empty-module": "^0.0.2",
    "eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.10.0",
    "file-loader": "1.1.11",
    "grunt": "1.0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "1.1.0",
    "jit-grunt": "0.10.0",
    "jshint": "2.9.5",
    "jshint-loader": "0.8.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "7.0.3",
    "style-loader": "0.21.0",
    "stylelint": "9.3.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "2.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "3.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "18.2.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "3.1.3",
    "uglify-js": "^3.4.9",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.2.7",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1",
    "webpack-shell-plugin": "^0.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^2.2.5",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^4.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-select": "^1.2.1",
    "react-values": "^0.2.4",
    "reactstrap": "^6.3.0",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

All my fils jsx files are as per below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that. React has to transform into js file in order to run in the browser

Normally you will need module bundle tool like webpack

You can view my full config [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js)

Let me know if you need any more help

Update: Here is how I transform jsx into js

```
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: ["babel-loader", "eslint-loader"]
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was also expecting to first transform into js and then minify. Do you know how to do this in asp.net core project?

Comment: You need to use webpack to transform jsx to js. You can view my webpack config [file](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js#L103-L107)

Comment: Thanks, let me try

Comment: I added webpack.config file in my asp.net core project but when i rebuild the project, it did not create anything in dist folder.

Comment: I added your Gruntfile.js also but not sure what all changes I should make.

Comment: Sorry but still don't know how to use webpack to transform jsx to js and then uglifyjs to minify it in asp.net core project with build process (or publish)

Comment: Did you get my concern?